# Insert Data in Google Calender Using Access Token

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, access-token

Following Google oAuth
-1. I have grabed the code via Client_ID & Secret_ID
-2. Exchange that code to get Access Token
-3. Now I want to Insert Delete & Search Data/Event In Google Calender using that access token available to me instead of users credentails. Please let me what i am doing wrong.

> Getting Error:
>   Execution of request failed: http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/imenmyself4u@gmail.com/private/full

Can anybody please help in this regard?

```
 Uri oCalendarUri;
ExtendedProperty oExtendedProperty;

 void Insert() 
{
    Google.GData.Calendar.EventEntry oEventEntry = new Google.GData.Calendar.EventEntry();
    oEventEntry.Title.Text = "Test Calendar Entry From .Net";
    oEventEntry.Content.Content =
      "Hurrah!!! I posted my first Google calendar event through .Net";


    Where oEventLocation = new Where();
    oEventLocation.ValueString = "New Zealand";
    oEventEntry.Locations.Add(oEventLocation);

    When oEventTime = new When(new DateTime(2014, 9, 26, 09, 0, 0),
 new DateTime(2014, 9, 26, 12 , 0, 0).AddHours(2));
    oEventEntry.Times.Add(oEventTime);

    oExtendedProperty = new ExtendedProperty();
    oExtendedProperty.Name = "SynchronizationID";
    oExtendedProperty.Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    myValue = oExtendedProperty.Value;
    oEventEntry.ExtensionElements.Add(oExtendedProperty);

    CalendarService oCalendarService = GAuthenticate();
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

    //Save Event        
    oCalendarService.Insert(oCalendarUri, oEventEntry);  
}

 private CalendarService GAuthenticate()
{

    oCalendarUri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/" +
                               sGoogleUserName + "/private/full");

    CalendarService oCalendarService = new CalendarService("CalendarSampleApp");
    string token = Session["token"].ToString();        
    oCalendarService.SetAuthenticationToken(token);

    return oCalendarService;
}
```

Comment: What's happening when you run the code you've already got? Presumably something goes wrong, but you haven't said what...

Comment: Additionally, is this the v2 API? You might want to consider using v3: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/calendar/v3

Comment: I am gettting this error:

Execution of request failed: http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/imenmyself4u@gmail.com/private/full

Comment: I am really stuck in google documentation and its versioning,
please guide me way that I can achieve my motive.
I have already access token that is required to grab or manipulate google api.

Comment: This code works perfect when used with
oCalenderService.SetCredentials("Username","Password")
instead of oCalenderService.SetAuthenticationToken("TOKEN")
inside GAuthenticate() method
but i want to use it with access token,
if its not possible then at least let me know a way that i can due to via access token. Thanks

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you start with the v3 calendar API I linked to before, rather than the GData-based API. It's rather more modern, and should be significantly easier to use... and as per the documentation: "This API is a subject to the Deprecation Policy and will be shutdown on November 17, 2014. Please use APIv3 instead". That said, if it's working when you call `SetCredentials`, it ought to be okay with `SetAuthenticationToken`. Please add all of this information into your question, where it belongs.

Comment: Sir I am already using v3 calender APi inorder to grab the access token, after that i dont find a way to do my intended job. i am trying it from last couple of days.

Comment: I'm confused then - because that doesn't look like v3 API code to me. (Looking at the documentation for the v3 `CalendarService`, I don't see an `Insert` method for example.) What do your `using` directives look like?

Comment: Sir i said i am using v3 api upto getting access token,
but after that i would love to use any way that help me to do my job whether it by via v3 api or whether it be via client library,
i am stuck how to go forward to achieve addition deletion and search in google calender once i have successfully get access token...

Comment: Ah, in code that you haven't shown? So why aren't you using the v3 API for the rest of your code? It may well be that using a token requested for the v3 API doesn't work with the v2 API, although I'm not 100% sure on that. I suggest you delete this question, try one specific task with the v3 API (e.g. adding an event, following the how-to guides here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/firstapp) and then posting a new question with details of that if you run into problems.

Comment: thanks let me give it a try what u said,

well thank you so much for your time, let me know anything i can do for you

Comment: can you please paste here an example that what i require to add an event in the google calender via v3 calender api?

Comment: No, because a) that's not what this question is about; b) you should try it for yourself first, following the how-to guides. There's a sample which creates a recurring event, so just adapt that.

Comment: Here what I found following v3 api is:
After OAuth 2.0 that gives access token,
now i have to post the data to google calender,

this is the link:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert#examples 

i went through insert method,
now i am here stuck that how to make url that accepts my argument and access token in order to post the data to google calender.

here is the request:
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList

Comment: Again, this should be in a *new question*, with plenty of context etc. Please see http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints. The v3 client library should hide a lot of the details of exactly what URLs it's posting too - I'd strongly encourage you to use it.

Comment: This Is Raw Data


    POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?sendNotifications=false&fields=location&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

    Content-Type:  application/json
    Authorization:  Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE
    X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

    {
    "end": {
    },
    "start": {
    },
    "location": "Dadu"
    }
  
Can You Please Help Me To Convert It To Asp.Net Http Request?

Comment: No. Post a new question - stop adding comments to this one. I won't be adding anything more here.

Comment: I m blocked to post more question, please help in this regard

Comment: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

how to convert raw data here in to asp.net http request so that it post data in google calender

Answer (score 0):

The api you are using is deprecated and will be shut down in November of this year (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_protocol). Please update the code to the latest API, you can find the migration guide here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/migration

Comment: Sir all i mean is how to call a rest api of google calender v3 from asp.net?
How to apply insert via rest api...

Comment: There is a dotnet client library: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/calendar/v3 Check out the samples at the bottom.